# What is meant by TCP connection in HTTP pipelining?

Tags: http, networking, tcp, pipeline, network-protocols

By definition, HTTP pipelining is a technique in which multiple HTTP requests are sent on a single TCP connection without waiting for the corresponding responses, according to Wikipedia, and some other resources. What is meant by TCP connection, is it the connection that starts when the client and server first communicate doing the 3 way handshake? Is it the same TCP stream? TCP stream meaning that the client and server communicate with each other using the same combination of ports.

Comment: *"What is meant by TCP connection, is it the connection that starts when the client and server first communicate doing the 3 way handshake?"* - sure it is. And I'm unable to imagine any other useful interpretation.

Comment: I ask this because,if I wanted to check whether there's HTTP pipeline used in a website by using Wireshark, there are 2 different answers. For example, if the HTTP messages were as follows: GET [domain name],200 OK,GET [picture1], GET [picture2],200 OK,200 OK, then there is pipeline used because there are 2 requests (GET) sent to a server without the server giving a response immediately (200 OK). However,if I follow the first GET request's TCP stream,it has 200 OK received in the stream,but it also has the second GET request right after,and then 200 OK. That would mean it doesn't use pipeline.

Comment: To check if pipelining is used you have to check each TCP connection independent from the other and consider only the order of request and response this connection, not the order of request and response combined over all requests in all connections.